# off64_t in Cygwin

Tags: c, makefile, cygwin, mingw, header-files

I have compiled program in minGW which I want to run in my computer which has Cygwin installed in my system. I have the following compilation error:

`error: 'off64_t' undeclared (first use in this function)`

I added the following to the CFLAGS in Makefile, but still having the same error.

`-D"_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE" -D"_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64"`

Can someone suggest what am I missing here and what I need to add?

Comment: maybe you need to include the correspondig header (if it's declared in one). Or do the typedef beforehand.

Comment: typedef is problematic as there are plenty of other functions / types as well

Comment: What header files are `#include`ed?  I'd think that if you're seeing declarations using `off64_t`, `off64_t` itself should be declared.

Comment: I don't understand your point. Is off64_t a variable that is part of another header? (like say "offset.h" or maybe even "stdlib.h") Then you have to include it. If it is a personal typdef, then do the typedef before you include the header which use it.

Answer (score 1):

Cygwin does not define the `off64_t` type. Instead, if defines `_off64_t`. If you want to compile your existing code with minimal changes, add the following at the top of your sources:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
typedef _off64_t off64_t;
```